# MVCCheckBoxList catering for a 1 to Many relationship

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, models

I have a class for which has a 1 to many relationship with another class. for this I will use class Car and class Gears. I need to create a form, which registers a car and the user needs to specify a choice of gears.

```
public class Car
{
   public int id { get; set; }
   public string desc { get; set; }
   public List<Gear> Gears { get; set; }
}
public class Gear
{
   public int gid { get; set; }
   public int gname { get; set; }
}
```

using asp.net MVC 5, I have a create form, which I have scaffolded to the Car model, and within the form, I wish to have a checkboxlist of gears,

I also have a ViewModel that I have provided for my checkboxlist which is as below:

```
public class GearsViewModel
{
    public Gear _gear {get; set; }
    public bool _isChecked {get; set;}
}
```

Controller looks like:

> Gears fetched from db context will be 
>   "GearR","Gear1","Gear2","Gear3","Gear4","Gear5","Gear6","Gear7"

```
public action Create()
{
    ViewBag.Gears = new SelectList(db.Gears, "gid","gname");
    List<GearViewModel> _gears= new List<GearViewModel>();
    foreach(Gear G in ViewBag.Gears)
    {
        _gears.Add(new GearViewModel(G, false));
    }
    ViewBag.GearsCheckList = _gears.ToList();
    return View();
}
```

Now, this is the part I'm getting stuck at, is how to display and capture details in the CreateView.

I need assistance on how to design the Create form and how I will capture the info.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, view models should not contain data models when editing. You view models should be (add validation and display attributes as appropriate)

```
public class CarVM
{
    public int? ID { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public List<GearVM> Gears { get; set; }
}
public class GearVM
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool IsSelected { get; set; }
}
```

and the GET method will be

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
    var gears = db.Gears;
    CarVM model = new CarVM
    {
        Gears = gears.Select(x => new GearVM
        {
            ID = x.gid,
            Name = x.gname
        }).ToList()
    };
    return View(model);
}
```

and the view will then be

```
@model CarVM
....
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    ..... // elements for editing ID and Description properties of CarVM
    @for (int i = ; i < Model.Gears.Count; i++)
    {
        <div>
            @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Gears[i].ID)
            @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Gears[i].Name) // include if your want to get this in the POST method as well
            @Html.CheckboxFor(m => m.Gears[i].IsSelected)
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Gears.IsSelected, Model.Gears[i].Name)
        </div>
    }
    <input type="submit" .... />
}
```

Then in the POST method

```
public ActionResult Create(CarVM model)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return View(model);
    }
    // To get the ID's of the selected gears
    IEnumerable<int> selected = model.Gears.Where(x => x.IsSelected).Select(x => x.ID);
    // Initialize your data models, save and redirect
}
```